# my embed message is editing but still got a error "interaction fails"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

my embed is getting modify but the all the other doesn't changed and discord says that interaction failed.

it look like i'm doing a time out on discord side. i think im missing how to modify the button part of it

also maybe this code can be refactor to be smaller feel free to let some tips

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const jsonData = fs.readFileSync('src/pld.json');
const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
const { getUsers, getFiche } = require('../../types/pld.js');// that go throw my json and give me only valid user and fiche

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('fiche')
    .setDescription('Affiche et gere vos fiches'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
      const users = await getUsers(data);
      const user = users.find(user => user.discord_id === interaction.user.id); //that way i find on the json who is asking for this commande 
      const fiche = await getFiche(user); //i only have the fiche of the user that is valid
      let x = 0;

      const emdedBuilder = (x) => {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle(fiche[x].name)
        .setDescription(fiche[x].description)
        .setAuthor({ name: interaction.member.nickname, iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/' + interaction.user.id + "/" + interaction.user.avatar, url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/' + interaction.user.id + "/" + interaction.user.avatar })
        .setTimestamp()
        .addFields(
          fiche[x].dod.map((dod) => ({
            name: dod.name,
            value: dod.done ? ":white_check_mark:" : ":x:",
            inline: true,
          }))
        )
        .setFooter({ text: `Fiche ${x + 1}/${fiche.length}` });
        
        return embed;
      }


      const previousButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('previous')
        .setLabel("⬅️")
        .setStyle(1)

      const nextButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('next')
        .setLabel("➡️")
        .setStyle(1)


      const response = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [emdedBuilder(x)], components: [
        new ActionRowBuilder({
          components: [
          ...(x > 0 ? [previousButton] : []),
           ...(x + 1  < fiche.length ? [nextButton] : [])
          ]
        })
      ], ephemeral: true });

      const collectorFilter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
      const confirmation = await response.awaitMessageComponent({ filter: collectorFilter, time: 600000 });
      if (confirmation.customId === 'previous' && x > 0) {
        x = x - 1;

        interaction.editReply({ embeds: [emdedBuilder(x)], components: [
          new ActionRowBuilder({
            components: [
            ...(x > 0 ? [previousButton] : []),
             ...(x + 1  < fiche.length ? [nextButton] : [])
            ]
          })], ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }
      if (confirmation.customId === 'next' && x < fiche.length -1) {
        x = x + 1;

        interaction.editReply({ embeds: [emdedBuilder(x)], components: [
          new ActionRowBuilder({
            components: [
            ...(x > 0 ? [previousButton] : []),
             ...(x + 1  < fiche.length ? [nextButton] : [])
            ]
          })], ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};
```

why is only the embed getting modify and also why discord give me a interaction fail even when my embed get modify